# Agebraically closed field equivalent definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, definition

Is this a valid equivalent definition of an algebraically closed field?

Let $ F $ be a field. Define a function $ f(x): F\longrightarrow F $ as a finite combination of the operations in $ F $ (addition, multiplication and their inverses). If the range of the function $ f $ is $ F $, then $ F $ is an algebraically  closed field.

My reasoning is that such function $ f $ should be a rational function
$ f(x)=\dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)} $ where $ p(x) $ and $ q(x) $ are polynomials with coefficients in $ F $, so for any fixed element $ y\in F $ I can write

$ f(x)=y $

$ \dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)}=y $

$ p(x)=yq(x) $

$ p(x)-yq(x)=0 $

As $ p(x)-yq(x) $ is a polynomial with coefficients in $ F $, if $ F $ is truly algebraically closed then there must be some root $ r\in F $ an so

$ f(r)=y $

As $ y $ is an arbitrary element of $ F $, then the range $ R $ of the function $ f $ satisfies $ R=F $

This should work for the field of complex numbers $ \mathbb{C} $ but does this work for any algebraically closed field?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, but as it reads to me right now, the following is a very simple counterexample : $F: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}, \ x \mapsto x + 1$.

Comment: I think you mean to say that you need this to be true for all possible such functions.

Comment: What you have shown here is that if $\mathbb{F}$ is algebraically closed field, and $F : \mathbb{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ is a function (well, partial function) that is given by a combination of the field operations, then it is surjective.

Comment: @jgon your right, I meant every possible function. Is this a valid definition of an algebraically closed field?

Comment: Well, if you remove inversion from the list of allowed operations, then it should be, yes. The problem with inversion is that e.g. $1/x$ is not surjective, since $1/x\ne 0$ for any $x$.